# JNA unsatisfied link error only when running on a windows tab

Tags: java, windows, exception, native, jna

I am trying to load a C dll from my Java code using JNA. The line in concern is

```
rlib = (rfidlib) Native.loadlibrary("rfidlib",rfidlib.class);
```

I placed the DLL in the same folder in a Windows machine and ran it. It ran fine. When I put it in the Windows/System32 folder also it worked fine. But when I copy this into a windows tab it throws the following exception.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: The speci
```

fied module could not be found.

```
    at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native Method)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native.java:1759)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:260)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:398)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:147)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:412)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:391)
    at com.kube.rfid.RFIDScanner.start(RFIDScanner.java:128)
    at com.kube.rfidscannertest.RFIDFrameMain$3.actionPerformed(RFIDFrameMai
n.java:106)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Sour
ce)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Sour
ce)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Sour
ce)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Sour
ce)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Both my Java version in the tab and the DLL are 64bit version. I have tried keeping the jar in both System32 folder in the tab as well as the jar executing location. Still I get this error. How can I address this issue? Please advice. It works fine in my windows machine.

Comment: What do you mean by a "windows tab"?

Comment: Its a tab which has Windows 8.1 installed.

Comment: You mean a "tablet"?  Set the system property `jna.library.path` to point to the directory where your DLL resides.

Comment: My DLL is at System32 folder. I have set the jna library path in the constructor of the main application before loading the dll. Still I get the unsatisfied link error. When I run without the jna library path, I get the unsatisfied link error with x86-64 issue. That means when I run with jna library path, it does find the DLL. But why does it still say unsatisfied link error?

Comment: @technomage it doesn't consider the jna.library.path line. The error says, "Unable to load library 'rfidlib' : Native library (win32-x86/rfidlib.dll) not found in resource path(<path of the jar>). But I have specified to load from the C:\Windows\System32 folder. Both in the program and while running as well. (java -Djna.library.path="C:\Windows\System32") - jar RFIDScannerTestApp.jar is how I gave it during run time. Nothing works. Please advice

Answer (score 1):

This was because the dependencies of the C DLL were missing. Used dependency walker to identify the dependencies and once they were installed it worked.